# Manipulate field:header of content element (old: How to replace a character in header with a select result?)

Tags: typoscript

I'm using the tx_news extension. When the plugin is used on a page and a header is set including a specific character, I want to replace this character with the number of news articles existing.
For example an editor maintains `there are # articles for your selected category` and the user should see `there are 8 articles for your selected category`. I hope you got, what I want to accomplish.

My TypoScript:

```
lib.anzahlNews = CONTENT
lib.anzahlNews { 
  table = tx_news_domain_model_news
  select {
    selectFields = COUNT(title) AS anzahl
    pidInList = 23
    where = archive = 0
  }  
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj.wrap = <span class="item_count"> | </span>
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = anzahl
  }
}
lib.stdheader {
    # some ohter unrelated stuff I'm doing


    stdWrap {
        # clear old datawrap
        dataWrap >

        innerWrap.cObject = COA
        innerWrap.cObject {
            5 = TEXT
            5.value = <header class="csc-header

            10 = TEXT
            10 {
                value = news-headline
                noTrimWrap = | ||
                if {
                    value = news_pi1
                    equals.field = list_type
                }
            }

            15 = TEXT
            15.value = ">

            20 = TEXT
            20 {
                value = | foo # bar
                stdWrap.replacement {
                    10 {
                        search.char = 35
                        replace < lib.anzahlNews
                    }
                }
                if {
                    value = news_pi1
                    equals.field = list_type
                }
            }

            25 = TEXT
            25.value = </header>
        }
    }
}
```

So I have two issues here:

1. I am unable to actually get the number out of my content element.
2. Only the `#` between `foo` and `bar` is replaced. (Results in `foo CONTENT bar`.) But the hash in the actual headline (the pipe) isn't replaced at all.

Sorry in advance, because I'm a mere beginner to TypoScript.

Can someone please show me where I'm wrong and show me the direction?
Thank you very much.

---

**// edit (2014-05-07 14:09):**

I found out, that `replace` only expects Strings - therefor I see "*CONTENT*", in my result.
I now try to use `stdWrap.split` to split the content of the header-field at the `#` and appanding the content from my `lib.anzahlNews` like this:

```
20 = TEXT
20 {
    value = | foo # bar
    stdWrap {
        split {
            token.char = 35

            # rendering of content
            cObjNum = 1 || 2
            1.current = 1
            1.wrap = |
            1.append < lib.anzahlNews
            2.current = 1
            2.wrap = |
        }
        if {
            value = news_pi1
            equals.field = list_type
        }
    }
}
```

That works so far, as it resolves my first issue of getting the wanted value at all. But the second issue still remains, that the actual content of the header-field isn't touched at all.

I need to manipulate the value of the header-field itself. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [tsref](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Replacement/Index.html#replacement) `replacement` comes with a stdWrap as well. so you might wanna try this:

```
....20 = TEXT
....20 {
     replacement {
          10 {
               search.char = 35
               replace.cObject < lib.anzahlNews
          }
     }
}
```

but since this above doesn't replace the # in your header text, try applying your second attempt to h2 headlines:

```
lib.char_replace {
         token.char = 35
         cObjNum = |*||*| 1 || 2
         1.current = 1
         2 < .1
}

lib.stdheader.10.2.split < lib.char_replace
lib.stdheader.10.2.split.1.append < lib.anzahlNews
```

maybe you get this working for all headlines with this:

```
lib.stdheader.10.setCurrent.split < lib.char_replace
lib.stdheader.10.setCurrent.split.1.append < lib.anzahlNews
```

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to let you know I read you answer. Currently I'm not working on a similar issue (and the old one is closed), so I can not verify it.
As soon as a similar task shows up, I'll try your solution and comment here again.

Comment: Just wanted to add, that after a lot of time a similar issue came across and your solution did work. Thank you. Even `lib.stdheader.10.setCurrent.replacement.10.replace.cObject < ...` is working. Which I prefer due to multiple replacement possiilities (like switch case).